# Matrix of a map has at least $\text{dim}\ \text{range}\ T$ non-zero entries.

Tags: linear-algebra

Reading a proof I found the following statement:

Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$, let $w_1,\cdots,w_m$ be a basis of W, let $r = \text{dim}\ \text{range}\ T$ , and let $s = \text{dim}\ \text{null}\ T$. Then there are $s$ basis vectors of $V$ which map to zero and $r$ basis vectors of $V$ with nontrivial representation as linear combinations of $w_1,\ldots,w_m$.

I can see that is true if I construct a basis of $V$ as $u_1\ldots,u_s,v_1,\ldots v_r$, where $u_1\ldots,u_s$ is a basis for $\text{null}\ T$. It is unclear why this should be true for any basis of $V$.

Here's the whole problem/proof for reference: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCZDK.png)

Comment: It is not true for an arbitrary basis. The basis needs to 'line up' with $\ker T$ for example.

Comment: The author is simply wrong. Consider the case where $n>m=1$ and $Tv_1=\cdots=Tv_n=w_1$ for instance.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The OP is not asking whether the assertion of the problem statement is true or not. They are asking why author says that *“there are $s$ basis vectors of $V$ which map to zero”*.

Comment: My bad! $ \ \ \ $